# Choi-Jamialkoski Theorem in Phase damping channel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator, linear-algebra

I am trying to replicate the solution I have to this problem provided by the instructor in the class where I am trying to use the Choi-Jamialkoski theorem to prove that Phase damping channel is completely positive.

The phase damping channel is given by the following map:
$\Lambda(\rho)=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1-P\\
1-P & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

Now the  Choi-Jamialkoski theorem states that $I_n\otimes(|\psi><\psi|)\geq0$

Where $|\psi><\psi|=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

and $I_n$ represents a 2x2 identity matrix in case of a qubit system.

What I don't understand is why I don't get a 8x8 matrix if I am doing a tensor product with Identity and also shouldn't the terms at off-diagonal extremities be zero. Please Help.

[image: The problem I am facing is marked in red]

Comment: Can you please write the equations out instead of use a photo graph?